# Visual studio after building give error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm Using Visual Studio 2017 To Work With Asp.Net Core Project that work on my pc but when copy it on my laptop to start working , after building it give me the error in below image , it work correctly on another device and i don't missing any directive .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSmIp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below Namespace to the project:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; not solve the problem

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http actually added but not solve the problem